# Question about three Primary Keys on a DAC

Tags: acumatica

In my case I have three Primary Keys,

Primary Key 2 is based on Primary Key 1,

Primary Key 3 is based on Primary Keys 1 and 2

My Question is how do you unset value of a Primary Key DAC Field?
Im trying to work on if I select on the Primary Key 1, Primary Keys 2 and 3 will be unset. I tried `cache.SetValueExt<DAC.Field>(data,null);` still no luck.

```
#region FundType
[PXDBString(3, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[RMPCFCustodianSetup.FundTypeList]
[PXDefault(RMPCFCustodianSetup.PCFDocType.PCF)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Fund Type", Required =true)]
public virtual string FundType { get; set; }
public abstract class fundType : IBqlField { }
#endregion

#region ReqPayClassID
[PXDBString(10, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<RMPCFSetup.classID,
            Where<RMPCFSetup.fundType, Equal<RMPCFRegister.fundType>>>),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.reqPayClassID),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.descr),
DescriptionField = typeof(RMPCFSetup.descr),
Filterable = true
)]
[PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<reqPayClassID>.IsRelatedTo<RMPCFSetup.classID>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Request Class", Required =true)]
public virtual string ReqPayClassID { get; set; }
public abstract class reqPayClassID : IBqlField { }
#endregion

#region RefNbr
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<RMPCFRegister.refNbr,
    Where<RMPCFRegister.fundType,Equal<Optional2<RMPCFRegister.fundType>>,
        And<RMPCFRegister.reqPayClassID,Equal<Optional2<RMPCFRegister.reqPayClassID>>>>>),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.fundType),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.reqPayClassID),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.refNbr),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.extRefNbr),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.descr),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.docAmt),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.dateRequested),
        typeof(RMPCFRegister.docStatus)
)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ref Nbr",Required =true)]
[AutoNumber(typeof(Search<RMPCFSetup.classNumberingID, 
    Where<RMPCFSetup.fundType, Equal<Optional2<RMPCFRegister.fundType>>,
        And<RMPCFSetup.classID,Equal<Optional2<RMPCFRegister.reqPayClassID>>>>>),
        typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
    public virtual string RefNbr { get; set; }
public abstract class refNbr : IBqlField { }
#endregion`
```

Comment: Changing the keys will get tricky since the cache is storing by key. But you could try to add to the dac field a formula to recall field defaulting which should clear out the values (or reset a default). Something like this on key2.... [PXFormula(typeof(Default<MyDac.key1>))] ... this will call field defaulting on the field you put this formula (key2) when t he key1 field changes. Repeat for key 3 pointing to key 2

Comment: There's two scenario where that could happen. Changing keys before saving will create a new record wiping out current values. After saving changing keys after will also create a new record. Keys aren't meant to be changed, I think it's a sign that database design should be improved.

Comment: You could consider using a numbering sequence as the unique key and validating that the other fields are unique without having the other fields declared as keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still an open issue in Acumatica. You can find the same incorrect behavior on the Rate Tables (PM206000) page. Acumatica's Support team suggests using Numbering Sequences as a unique key for this situation.

Comment: Alternative as mentioned is Numbering Sequence but also an identity field so you do not need a numbering sequence setup if it is not necessary. You can also use PXCheckUnique on your 3 fields if you want to make sure they are not duplicates after using a single alternative key. Then you can use the PXFormula Default logic to get the fields to clear automatically without having to write code in the graph

Comment: Okay, I will try the PXFormula, to give you insight. my Key1 is like Document Type, My Key2 is the ClassType with configuration what numbering sequence will be used, the my Key 3 is a reference number, where is depending what DocumentType is used on Key1 and what ClassType is used on Key2.

Comment: edited post, included DAC Code